# Obtener rol de usuario con Eloquent de Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

Lo que sucede es que tengo una BD donde un Usuario solo puede tener un Rol y un Rol puede tener muchos usuarios.

En el modelo User tengo esto:

```
public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
```

En el modelo Role tengo esto:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

Creo que esta parte esta bien, solo que necesito recuperar el nombre del rol del usuario que este logueado y mostrarlo en pantalla, en este caso la plantilla AdminLTE requiere de una funcion el modelo User.

Probe con esto y me retorna el id del rol.

```
public function adminlte_desc(){
        return $this->roles_id;
    }
```

Luego probe con esto y no me devuelve nada, que puede ser ?

```
public function adminlte_desc(){
        return $this->role()->where('id', $this->roles_id)->first();
    }
```

Disculpen soy nuevo, les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: La plantilla AdminLTE necesita de una función llamada adminlte_desc que esté dentro del modelo User y que está retorne el nombre rol. Pero solo consigo retornar el ID del rol.

Comment: Me produce este error Attempt to read property "name" on null

Comment: Perdón, la convención sugiere role_id?

Comment: Si bro, muchas gracias. No implemente bien la convención y por eso no podía acceder a la propiedad. Ahora sí funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Por un lado, Eloquent determina el nombre de la clave foránea predeterminada examinando el nombre de la relación y agregandole como sufijo un `_` seguido del nombre de la columna de clave primaria del modelo principal. Ref: [One To Many (Inverse) / Belongs To](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

Dado que el nombre de la relación es `role()`, la llave foránea que espera encontra Eloquent es `role_id` y no `roles_id` como la que tienes en tu modelo.

Para resolverlo, puedes explicitar cuál es la llave foránea al definir la relación:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Role::class, 'roles_id');
}
```

Luego, en cualquier función dentro de la clase `User`, puedes retornar el nombre del `Role` relacionado con:

```
return $this->role->name
```